# How can I get `man` not to spew garbage about unsupported macros?

Tags: terminal, macos, command-line

I just used `brew` to install the latest GNU Screen.  Afterwards, I noticed that `man screen` shows a bunch of garbage lines.  The man page displays as it should but once I exit I see a bunch of lines like:

```
mandoc: /usr/local/share/man/man1/screen.1:711:4: UNSUPP: ignoring macro in table: br
mandoc: /usr/local/share/man/man1/screen.1:713:4: UNSUPP: ignoring macro in table: br
mandoc: /usr/local/share/man/man1/screen.1:721:4: UNSUPP: ignoring macro in table: br
mandoc: /usr/local/share/man/man1/screen.1:730:4: UNSUPP: ignoring macro in table: br
mandoc: /usr/local/share/man/man1/screen.1:750:2: UNSUPP: ignoring macro in table: I screen
mandoc: /usr/local/share/man/man1/screen.1:1463:4: UNSUPP: ignoring macro in table: br
mandoc: /usr/local/share/man/man1/screen.1:1469:4: UNSUPP: ignoring macro in table: br
mandoc: /usr/local/share/man/man1/screen.1:1475:4: UNSUPP: ignoring macro in table: br
```

Some googling suggests this is because Apple's `man` is using mandoc instead of `roff` or any variant thereof, and that mandoc doesn't support formatting inside of tables.

I don't particularly care that I'm not getting all the formatting intended for this man page, as it looks fine and completely readable.  But I don't want all the garbage displayed after I exit the man page.

How can I get rid of this?

(I'm open to solutions which would suppress the error, solutions which would force `man` to use groff or similar so I get all formatting, and solutions which would replace `man` entirely so it's no longer hardcoded to use mandoc.)

This is on Mac OS 12.7.1.

A couple of links found during my search:

- [Apple forums discussion about `man` not using roff](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/254272327)
- [GitHub issue for pandoc's man pages where this error came up as well](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/8045)

Comment: Are you using the built-in man(1) or the Homebrew version? The latter is more likely to be compatible with GNU-specific formatting in man pages. Failing that, you could just invoke man with standard error suppressed.

Comment: The correct answer is to file a bug against Homebrew and get the page fixed.

Comment: @LincD. `brew install man` seems to indicate there is no such thing as a homebrew version of man.  And trying with stderr suppressed doesn't prevent the garbage.  I'm speculating that the garbage is printed to stdout, before the man page is actually rendered in the pager.

Comment: @MarcWilson why against homebrew instead of against gnu screen?

Comment: Homebrew will either fix the page, or tell you to report it upstream (or ignore you, but at least report it).

Comment: @Wildcard Homebrew are the ones packaging it for the Mac, so that's where you would start.  If you wanted to be 100% detailed, you could always compare what Homebrew is packaging with whatever is in the GNU screen package.

Comment: Addtl data point... MacPorts is also packaging GNU screen and aren't patching the man page either.

Comment: If the error messages are being written to stdout, you could pipe the output through grep to suppress them.

Comment: FWIW, `man` on Sonoma 14.3 just shows one line of error: `This manpage is not compatible with mandoc(1) and might display incorrectly.`

Comment: Would using GNU info to read your manpage work ? Again, would piping the results of man to `less`again work for you- `man screen | less -is` ? MacPorts version of `man` fixes the issue.

Comment: @fd0 instructions for how to install macports man might be an acceptable solution then.  I don't want to monkey with GNU info, I've used it before but I prefer man pages.

Comment: MacPorts ships `man(1)`, I don't know why.